# Rails 3.2.1 - wrong number of arguments (3 for 1) in app.call(env) - any idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've just upgraded my app to Rails 3.2.1, and when I start up the server, I get this: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)). It's happening with a bunch of my gems, but also this rack middleware I include.

```
def call(env)
  env['PATH_INFO'] = env['PATH_INFO'].downcase
  @app.call(env)
end
```

Has something about the call function changed?

Comment: Could you include a stack trace into the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails upgrade and the middleware were both red herrings. Omniauth changed the way strategies work https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/529 and that was breaking everything in my app.

Doubt this answer will be useful to anyone, but thanks for the help.